auxetic expansion
I am trying to obtain the expansion of the auxetic structure, which should look like something in the picture, but I could not figure out how to do it. Could you help me?
I really appreciate any help you can provide.


The mesh is quite messy, but the rig should be like this:
A_Top doesn't have a parent (Alt P to remove it)
B_Top is child of A_Top
A2 has an IK constraint targeting A_Top, chain lenght 2
B2 has an IK constraint targeting B_Top, chain lenght 2
Moving A_Top on Z axis will do the job.

